# SpriteKit animation stops unexpectedly

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit

I'm trying to debug a very strange behaviour of SpriteKit animation. It's quite easy to reproduce:

1. Create a new Game project in Xcode leaving all the options unchanged.
2. Open GameScene.swift and change line #23 from **label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2.0))** to **label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.2))**
3. Connect your phone and start a debugging session, observe how the text (Hello, World!) fades in and appears in full brightness. Well, so far, so good.
4. Stop the application from Xcode and start it again clicking its icon on your phone.
5. Observe how the text, although visible, is not faded in completely.

I found this trying to understand why my animation just stops half the way when my application loads. I assume that somehow the view stops refreshing if some initialisation step is longer than the animation but I don't know how to fix this. I also noticed that if you click on the screen it refreshes and the animated view appears in the final state.

iOS version: 10.3

Comment: Well found and isolated!

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a serious issue with iOS11 and SpriteKit. The Game Scene during the transition is getting paused automatically (but only in iOS11).

After transitioning to the scene run

`myScene.isPaused = false`

and it should fix the issue, and should have no adverse affects when the game is run on iOS10

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Where do you put `myScene.isPaused = false`? I tried to put into `didMove` - didn't have any effect. And, I forgot to mention, the target version which exhibits the problem is 10.3

Comment: if you want to put it in the didMove inside the scene it would just be isPaused = false if you want to put it in the GameViewController put it after the presentScene line and use the sceneName.isPaused = false

Comment: Tried both ways - didn't work, the animation halts, sorry.

Comment: do it during `viewDidAppear`.  This should be fired after the scene is displayed on the view.